# How to bind two ip to one domain name for failover solution in Linux (Bind) or Windows server 2008 DNS

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2, bind, centos6

How to bind two ip to one domain name for fail over solution in Linux (Bind) or Windows server 2008 DNS ?

Comment: Very low TTLs or Round Robin DNS, if you want DNS only solutions. This is very probably a duplicate question though.

Answer (score 6):

Simple, create two A records with different IPs for the same domain.

That said, this is *not* a good solution for failover. You should use a load balancer of some kind, whether it's Windows NLB, HAProxy, or a hardware device like an F5 Big-IP or Cisco ACE. Then, create a single A record for the domain and point it at the VIP for your site on the load balancer.

If you do DNS round robin, which is the term for what you are asking about, 50% of your requests will go to the failed web server.

---

Edit: Since you're apparently talking about site resiliency and not simply server resiliency (a constraint not originally presented in your question), you should look into something like [Anycast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anycast) for seamless site-based failover. If you can handle downtime, set a single DNS record pointing at your primary site with a low TTL. Then, manually change the record to point to the services at your second site. This *will* incur downtime and you're at the mercy of other DNS servers respecting your TTL, which many will not.

Comment: Thanks MDMarra, It's a site failover  solution. We will request our ISP (DNS service provider) to add two public IP in A records. Hope it will work not the web server in difference datacentre.

Comment: Even in a site-failover, DNS Round Robin is *still* not ideal. Please don't confuse my answer to your question as a recommendation for how to handle failover. It rarely ever makes sense to use DNS as a failover tool.

Comment: I think Windows NLB is the cheaper way for fail over solution. But one of the web server is locate at another site. Both site use site to site VPN connected. For File server to share the web site , we have a software to sync these content to another site at same time. So if the primary site down, it will fail over to another site with same web content. Is it possible to work on this solution ?

Comment: I think you should consider hiring someone with a background in this type of thing to consult for you on this project. Stretching an NLB cluster across two physically separate sites isn't the way to do this.